# TelegramBOT | Node.js | Как отменить слушание обработчика в конце события?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

Суть задания такова, в конце обработчика события и выполнения функции завершить слушатель текста.
Вместо консоль log-a там была бы функция.
Использую **Telegraf.js**.

Буду благодарен за любые грамотные ссылки на уроки, или решение задачи + где можно детальнее изучить Telegraf.js.

```
bot.hears("Авторизовать", (ctx) => {
            ctx.reply('Введи {userId} {accessLevel}\nЕсли юзер уже есть - обновит статус, если нет - авторизует.')

            const auth_func = async (ctx) => {
                const auth_massege = ctx.message.text
                console.log(auth_massege);
                bot.off("text", auth_func)
            };
            bot.on("text", auth_func)
        });
```

**Ошибка:** TypeError: bot.off is not a function

Пробовал таким вариантом решения, никак. Хотя видел что у ребят у некоторых работало.

Comment: вместо bot.on написать `bot.once("text", auth_func)`?